# Scheme cons problem creating a proper list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I'm having trouble appending to a list in this scheme function.

The function is meant to take in 2 arguments, and return a list consisting of the 2nd elements the number of times specified in the 1st element. For example, if you call `(make-list? 5 4)` your output should be `(4 4 4 4 4)`.

The problem is when I use `cons`, I get `((((4 . 4) . 4) . 4) . 4)` instead. As I understand it, I am appending to the end of the entire list as an object each time, *not the last element of it as I want to*. I am unsure of how to fix it.

Here is my function, suggestions on how to cons to the last element instead of the list as an object would be great. (or other suggestions if that is not the only/real problem.)

```
;make-list
(define make-list?
  (lambda (N A)
    (if (= N 1)
       A
       (cons (make-list?(- N 1) A ) A)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Purely a style comment, but most of the time functions that end with '?' are predicates that return true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is that *every* list is terminated by `'()`.  In this case, it might be more illustrative to make your base case 0 and have it return the empty list:

```
(define make-list?
  (lambda (n a)
    (if (zero? n)
        '()
        (cons a (make-list (sub1 n) a)))))
```

So in this example, if we've hit 0, then we return the empty list to "cap off" the list we're building.

Comment: thanks, added that to my function. you were of course correct I wanted proper lists.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is an annoying one, and is caused by how cons cells work. (cons a b) creates a cons cell if b is not a list. By reordering so you're adding the atom to the list, not the other way around, and making it so the innermost item is a list (by the way, you could use (cons A '()) instead of (list A) in the following definition) you get around this.

```
(define make-list?
  (lambda (N A)
    (if (= N 1)
       (list A)
       (cons A (make-list?(- N 1) A ))
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It would have taken me a while to realize that property of cons. Great answer that cleared everything up.